# Is it possible to refer to id/class inside View in ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass value from 'class' in the View to controller and save it to database. Date picked by the user is stored in class 'finalDate' (about 100 rows with such date field and 'Save' button):

View:

```
<tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.custName)
           </td>
           <td class="choice">
                <input class="finalDate" type="date">                
           </td>
           <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Save","Update", new { cust = item.custName, manualDate = "{finalDate.value}" }) //can I pass class (or id) in that way?

           </td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Update(string cust, DateTime? manualDate)
        {

            _docs.UpdateData(cust, manualDate); //method UpdateData takes args and saves changes to db 

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The issue is that no error shows up. Nothing has been changed to db anyway. So I'm wondering if:

1. I pass class value to ActionLink correctly (and is it possible at all)?
2. I need to wrap up my View code in `<form action="@Url.Action("ActionName", "Home"))" method="post">` to send data to server?
3. Add [HttpPost] to ActionResult?

Comment: I don't think "class" works that way and it doesn't make sense to me.  Class is for CSS and not values.  Otherwise you'd be getting the value from every field on the form with that class.

Comment: ok so how can I take value from this date field and pass to controller?